# Matching greater than HTML character with Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use re.compile to match a value on a web page

My web page contains the following HTML:

```
<div id="paginate">
&nbsp;<strong>1</strong>
&nbsp;<a href="http://www.link2.com/">2</a>
&nbsp;<a href="http://www.link3.com/">3</a>
&nbsp;<a href="http://www.link2.com">&gt;</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.link20.com/">Last &rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

My regex is as follows:

```
re.compile('<a href="(.+?)">&gt;</a>').findall()
```

This returns

```
['http://www.link2.com/">2</a>
&nbsp;<a href="http://www.link3.com">3</a>
&nbsp;<a href="http://www.link2.com/']
```

I only want to get the href of the link which contains the greater than symbol as it's label?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regular expressions should not be used here.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `re.findall()`:

```
>>> re.findall('<a href="(.+?)">&gt;</a>', html)
['http://www.link4.com']
```

Note that you really should be parsing HTML with an HTML parser and not regex. I suggest [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> print soup.find('a', text='>')
<a href="http://www.link4.com">&gt;</a>
>>> print soup.find('a', text='>')['href']
http://www.link4.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty new to Python and will look into BS. In this case, it's a small XBMC plugin that I am writing and unfortunately using re.findall still returns the same as before. If I change the &gt; to a 2 it finds the href for link2.com successfully

Comment: @RichardLindsay Are you using the code I'm using? in my case `html` is just what you posted in your question

Comment: Instead of the html, i'm passing a variable named link which contains the html. Is that wrong?

Comment: @RichardLindsay Nah that should be right. Tbh, this is really why you should be using a parser and not regex :p

Comment: Yeah, what I don't get though is that it's worked ok for my other regex queries. It must be something to do with the &gt;

Comment: @RichardLindsay Most likely, yes. I'm not extremely knowledgeable in this topic, so I can't help you there I'm afraid :(

Comment: No probs, you've introduced me to BS. I'll look into that, cheers

Comment: Haha, hold on, BS doesnt work either. When i try print soup.find('a', text='>')['href'] I receive the error 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable and when I try print soup.find('a', text='&gt;')['href'] I receive the error 'string indices must be integers'

Comment: @RichardLindsay You did do `soup = BS(html)` right? Because that's incredibly weird

Comment: I did. I'm going to have a bash at converting the HTML using soup = BS(link, convertEntities=BS.HTML_ENTITIES) and see what happens

Comment: @RichardLindsay Sorry mate, I can't help you any further